# Furnace Fan Only Turns On With Heat

Tags: electrical, hvac, thermostat, furnace, central-air

Recently had a mini split installed, and the HVAC tech recommended that I occasionally turn on the fan to circulate cold air throughout the house. Tech changed the thermostat to a Honeywell Prestige system (RED LINK). I went to turn on the fan this evening and nothing ... Fan still turns on when the electric furnace is in heat mode but will not turn on "ON" or "CIRCULATE". Anyone have any ideas what might be the issue?

Comment: Did it work at all when the Tech was there? With many thermostats you can remove the front to show the wiring connections to the base - if you can do that, upload a picture showing the wiring.

Comment: Call the tech and complain that it was not installed properly.  Also validate the original thermostat had a fan only switch.